# Read/Write Enum to/from XML

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm writing an enum value with an XmlWriter, and it look something like this in the xml:

```
<Tile>Plain</Tile>

writer.WriteValue(tile.ID.ToString()); // ID's type is the enum
```

Plain being one of the enum values. Now when I try to read this, though it won't work.

```
(TileID)reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(TileID), null);
```

I do this when my reader.Name == "Tile", which should work, though it apparently can't convert the string to my enum. Is there any way to either fix the writing, so I don't have to do the .ToString() (since if I don't I get an error: "TileID cannot be cast to string".) or fix the reading?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you want to do `ToString()`?

Comment: I don't not want to do it, though if there is an other WriteValue-ish function that doesn't need this and can write my enum properly that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using `Enum.TryParse`

```
var enumStr = reader.ReadString();
TitleID id;
if (!Enum.TryParse<TitleID>(enumStr, out id)
{
    // whatever you need to do when the XML isn't in the expected format
    //  such as throwing an exception or setting the ID to a default value
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is such a simple thing, learning new stuff every day :D

Comment: @TheOddler FYI - if you are going to set the ID enumeration to a default value if the parsing fails, do not initialize the variable to it, set it after the `TryParse` call tells you the parsing fails, as the `TryParse` function will set the value to some default

Answer (score 3):

You will probably have to use `Enum.Parse`. I threw this together for a project at work recently:

```
public static T ParseTo<T>(string value) {
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
}
```

It just makes the casting a bit cleaner. I don't need any error checking because of the very strict XML generation tests we have.. you may want to add some.

Usage for you:

```
var idString = reader.ReadString();
TileID tileId = StaticClassYouPutItIn.ParseTo<TileID>(idString);
```

Comment: Thanks, very good answer :D Though with my wacky xml's the TryParse thing is probably a better idea. Thanks!

Comment: @TheOddler Hence why I said you may want to add some error checking :) Glad it could help.